# How to select the previous selectedItem when Configurations changes?

Tags: android, spinner

I have a issue about spinner. I have many images in spinner when I select some image it shows the image and if I change the orientation like change to landscape its selected item list starts pointing the top one in the list. How shall I prevent to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Override `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and, as part of whatever you return, include `getSelectedItemPosition()` from the `Spinner`.

Step #2: In `onCreate()`, call `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`. If it is not `null`, that is the object you returned in Step #1 above. Use the value from it to call `setSelectedPosition()` on the `Spinner` to set the selection to whatever it was before.